# Suffixes in merge in R

Tags: r, function, merge

I have two data frames which I need to merge and which have common column names.
After the merge, I want to sum over column names that have the same names and retain only one column. Merge adds suffixes (.x and .y) which I need to get rid of beforehand. I do this with the code below and it works (for brevity, the summing part is omitted). This works:

```
> x=data.frame(c("2015-05-31","2015-06-30","2015-07-31"),c(100,200,150))
> colnames(x)=c("Date","AAPL")
> x[,1]=as.Date(x[,1],origin="1970-01-01")
> 
> x
        Date AAPL
1 2015-05-31  100
2 2015-06-30  200
3 2015-07-31  150
> 
> y=data.frame(c("2015-05-31","2015-06-30","2015-07-31"),c(3000,8000,2000))
> colnames(y)=c("Date","AAPL")
> y[,1]=as.Date(y[,1],origin="1970-01-01")
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> tt=merge(x,y,by='Date',all=TRUE)
> 
> rename=colnames(tt)
> rename=gsub(".x","",rename,fixed=TRUE)
> rename=gsub(".y","",rename,fixed=TRUE)
> colnames(tt)= c(rename)
> 
> tt
        Date AAPL AAPL
1 2015-05-31  100 3000
2 2015-06-30  200 8000
3 2015-07-31  150 2000
```

However, I would like to omit the rename part, and I have tried empty suffixes:

```
> tt=merge(x,y,by='Date',all=TRUE)
> tt=merge(x,y,by='Date',all=TRUE,suffixes = c("",""))
Warning message:
In merge.data.frame(x, y, by = "Date", all = TRUE, suffixes = c("",  :
  column name ‘AAPL’ is duplicated in the result
> tt
        Date AAPL AAPL
1 2015-05-31  100 3000
2 2015-06-30  200 8000
3 2015-07-31  150 2000
```

I get the error message displayed above but this works as well. The problem is that if I put the code with the suffixes = c("","") in a function, then I get the error message and no data frame tt is produced. Any idea how to solve this?

Here is the function:

```
out=function(){
tt=merge(shares,spin,by='Date',all=TRUE,suffixes = c("",""))
tt=merge(tt,ma5,by='Date',all=TRUE,suffixes = c("",""))
return(tt)
}

out()
```

Comment: Why do you need to get rid of suffixes? Sounds like an XY-problem to me, and in my opinion double column names should be avoided.

Comment: Because, as mentioned in the text, I sum up over column names with same names only.

Comment: But I think that would be a better problem to solve, fairly easy to do with regex. Generally, when things throw errors or warnings like this it's a sign there might be a better solution. Working on one for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited the data, to add one more doubled column and a single one.

```
x=data.frame(Date= as.Date(c("2015-05-31","2015-06-30","2015-07-31")),
             AAPL=c(100,200,150),
             v2=1:3,
             v3=1:3)

y=data.frame(Date=as.Date(c("2015-05-31","2015-06-30","2015-07-31")),
             AAPL=c(3000,8000,2000),
             v2=1:3)
```

Approach 1: use rbind.fill from plyr, and then dcast with sum as aggregating function (missings were removed with melt, what you want to do with it depends on data)

```
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)
tt1 <- melt(rbind.fill(x,y),id.var="Date",na.rm=T)
res <- dcast(data=tt1, Date~variable,fun.aggregate = sum)
> res
        Date AAPL v2 v3
1 2015-05-31 3100  2  1
2 2015-06-30 8200  4  2
3 2015-07-31 2150  6  3
```

Approach 2, if you really want to use merge (this can probably be shorter, but I don't directly see how)

```
tt=merge(x,y,by='Date',all=TRUE)
merged_pattern <- "\\.[x|y]"
#vector of columns you need to sum because they are double
cols_to_sum <- unique(gsub(merged_pattern,"",
                    grep(merged_pattern,colnames(tt),value=T)))

res <- do.call("cbind", list(tt[,!grepl(merged_pattern,colnames(tt))]
                             ,sapply(cols_to_sum, function(x){
  rowSums(tt[,grepl(x,colnames(tt))])
}))
)
res

> res
        Date v3 AAPL v2
1 2015-05-31  1 3100  2
2 2015-06-30  2 8200  4
3 2015-07-31  3 2150  6
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answers. Could you maybe elaborate on the Error: object 'merged_pattern' not found ?

Comment: My apologies; it is a regular expression that got lost in copy-pasting. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can use {powerjoin} to solve this very succinctly

```
library(powerjoin)
power_left_join(x, y, by = "Date", conflict = `+`)
#         Date AAPL
# 1 2015-05-31 3100
# 2 2015-06-30 8200
# 3 2015-07-31 2150
```